# How to check if files with a certain extension exist with wildcard in Bash

Tags: bash, wildcard, file-extension

I have a bunch of files to process under the directory: /project/abc/outboud/, the file extension is .txt and .dat. How do I check different file extensions with a wildcard *?

My code:

```
DAT=/project/abc/outboud/*.dat
if [[ -f $DAT ]]; then echo "DAT files"; else echo "TXT files"; fi
```

code does not echo DAT files, any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Why do you use `set -f` if you want to use a glob?

Comment: What do you mean?